# Nginx - Reverse proxy to multiple backends

Tags: node.js, nginx

please before to mark this as duplicated read my own case, it's a bit different from others.

I'm developing multiple node.js endpoints that I'd like to have under the same domain.

These services do respond to something like:

- `/user/:user_id/authorization` - base path for the authorization service
- `/user/:user_id/log` - base path for the log service

And so on.

The first part `/user/:user_id/` is the same to all services, it's just a REST way to pass the user id inside the path instead of using the Authentication header.

**Is there a way I can reverse-proxy NGINX to these webservices since they are using the same base path?**

Another question: if NGINX is not used for caching content, may it downgrade node.js performances (for example if its performances are worst than node.js) if it's reverse proxying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With nginx you can do whatever routing you want, look here as a start point: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html and http://nginx.org/r/location

---

> Another question: if NGINX is not used for caching content, may it downgrade node.js performances (for example if its performances are worst than node.js) if it's reverse proxying?

[node.js itself or nginx frontend for serving static files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967887/node-js-itself-or-nginx-frontend-for-serving-static-files)

Also see: http://www.aosabook.org/en/nginx.html

Comment: Thanks for these resources, I'm reading them all. I've also seen your comment on Vadim answer and I checked out "IfIsEvil", they say it's something that works or not, is not a random behaviour, so if I configure it and it worked on tests it will always work... Otherwise they purpose different approaches if any. This is my question: do I have any other way to do that? I'm reading "request_processing", should I use differend "location" sections? Would it do the job?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, using locations is preferred way in nginx. It makes config clearer. Moreover, the "location" is optimized as effective search tree and works faster. Different tools for different tasks. I know that apache guys like to programm in its configs, but nginx is different.

Comment: Also note, that you can have embed location blocks, like: `location /user/ { location ~ ^/user/(?:.*)/authorization$ { .. } }`

Answer (score 0):

If i clearly understand your question you need something like this:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name default;
    root                /var/www/;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    location / {
        if (-f $request_filename) {
                access_log      off;
                expires         30d;
                break;
        }
        error_log       off;
        error_page 404  = @node;
    }

    location @node {
        if ($uri ~ "/user/(.*)/authorization") { proxy_pass     http://127.0.0.1:8080; } #authorization service
        if ($uri ~ "/user/(.*)/log")           { proxy_pass     http://127.0.0.1:8081; } #log service

        proxy_next_upstream     error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_ignore_headers    X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
    }
}
```