# AWS Deployment NGINX Connection Refused for Node.JS Project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Have a Standard `Node.JS` Project. When Deployed on `AWS`, The Server is Running and initializing Properly But `NGINX` gives the Below Error

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2015/04/18 10:49:56 [error] 4445#0: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XX.XX.XX, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "stagingmyproj.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/04/18 10:49:56 [error] 4445#0: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XX.XX.XX, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/favicon.ico", host: "stagingmyproj.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/04/18 10:50:05 [error] 4445#0: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XX.XX.XX, server: , request: "GET /vendor/login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/vendor/login", host: "stagingmyproj.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/04/18 10:50:06 [error] 4445#0: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XX.XX.XX, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/favicon.ico", host: "stagingmyproj.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/04/18 10:50:28 [error] 4445#0: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XX.XX.XX, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "stagingmyproj.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2015/04/18 10:50:28 [error] 4445#0: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XX.XX.XX, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/favicon.ico", host: "stagingmyproj.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

I am using the AWS Elastic BEanstalk Console. Not the Command Line Tool. Not sure If I am even using NGInx.

I am not a Dev Ops Person, But I don't have any clue about NGinx. What's the best possible solution out of here?

Cheers and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try to check the version of nginx you are using. you will need version 1.3.13 or later. i would recommend 1.6

Comment: Could you provide more configuration details, like ports, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer that I answered previously. A lot of people have issues with one part, so the answer tries to explain everything from your browser down to nginx: [elastic beanstalk weird nginx configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070088/elastic-beanstalk-weird-nginx-configuration/26075561#26075561)

It should at least give you a starting point for debugging and being able to eliminate issues.

Comment: Thanks @josh-davis. Works great. I had a problem with YAML Syntax probably! :(