# Node.js http-proxy allow HTTPS

Tags: node.js, http-proxy

I have an application that creates a proxy server and returns the url requests when a page is accessed, but it works only for http web pages and when I'm trying to access a https address then I get `Secure Connection Failed` in the browser.

To solve this, I generated a Self-Signed Certificate for `localhost:8080` from [here](http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/), but still can't access secured web pages...

This is my code:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var fs = require('fs');

var proxy = httpProxy.createServer({
  ssl: {
    key:  fs.readFileSync('ssl_key_8080.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert:  fs.readFileSync('ssl_cert_8080.pem', 'utf8')
  },
  target:'https://localhost:8080',
  secure: true
});

proxy.listen(443);

var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var options = {
    target: 'http://' + req.headers.host,
  };
  req.host = req.headers.host;
  proxy.web(req, res, options, function(err){
    console.log('err', err)
  });
}).listen(8080);

proxy.on('proxyReq', function (proxyReq, req, res) {
  console.log('request url', JSON.stringify(req.url, true, 2));
});
```

Is there something that I'm not doing right? I followed the instructions from [http-proxy docs](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#using-https)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you have a self signed certificate and you are using the secure flag in the proxy settings object, from the docs

> You can activate the validation of a secure SSL certificate to the
>   target connection (avoid self signed certs), just set secure: true in
>   the options.

```
    var proxy = httpProxy.createServer({
  ssl: {
    key:  fs.readFileSync('ssl_key_8080.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert:  fs.readFileSync('ssl_cert_8080.pem', 'utf8')
  },
  target:'https://localhost:8080',
  secure: true
});
```

If you remove the secure flag, you might get an error in your browser that the route isn't safe.

In the context of your code.

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var fs = require('fs');

var proxy = httpProxy.createServer({
  ssl: {
    key:  fs.readFileSync('ssl_key_8080.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert:  fs.readFileSync('ssl_cert_8080.pem', 'utf8')
  },
  target:'https://localhost:8080'
});

proxy.listen(443);

var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var options = {
    target: 'http://' + req.headers.host,
  };
  req.host = req.headers.host;
  proxy.web(req, res, options, function(err){
    console.log('err', err)
  });
}).listen(8080);

proxy.on('proxyReq', function (proxyReq, req, res) {
  console.log('request url', JSON.stringify(req.url, true, 2));
});
```

Comment: Still not working, now I get `The connection was reset` in the browser

Comment: Are you running node as root?  This explains why it is needed to listen on port 443 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579028/node-js-https-server-cant-listen-to-port-443-why

Comment: You can either run as root or you can change line 13 to listen on a different port

Comment: Yes, I'm running node as root with sudo node

Comment: Have you got the logs from the node process.  I've put it up on Glitch if you want to play around on there? https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/8e40de60-f8e9-4400-837d-8d87d4151cbd

Comment: Should it do something when I press the "Show" button on the top? I haven't used Glitch before and don't know how it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144042/discussion-between-valip-and-peter-grainger).