# HTTPS Server in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wondering how can I create a https server in node listening on Port 443 in a way that when I type :

```
https://my.ip.address:443 it should work.
https://my.ip.address it should work.
my.ip.address (without the https://) it should work and redirect me to https)
my.ip.address:443 it should work and redirect me to https
```

So far I was only able to make the first and second url work.

So my question is how can I make it also work for the other two possibilities (the final two). Thanks

Comment: Rule of thumb, never expose node to the world. Use a reverse proxy like nginx. You could do all the above in nginx, ie without having to expose node + port 443

Comment: @SwarajGiri: What's the harm with exposing node to the world?

Comment: @SwarajGiri — I'm pretty sure you can't handle the final case with nginx (or anything else).

Comment: @Quentin - With nginx, you dont have the port. It would basically boil down to `http` to `https` redirection.  No?

Comment: @Matt - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16770780/710005

Comment: @SwarajGiri — No. The port is always there. It may or may not be entered into the URL, but that is up to the client, not the server.

Comment: @Quentin - What i meant with having nginx is that you only expose port 80 and let nginx proxy requests to node on port 443. In that scenario, case 4 of the question, would be a mere http to https redirection.

Comment: @SwarajGiri — Disabling encryption between the web server and the browser is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you type `my.ip.address` into a browser's address bar then it will request `http://my.ip.address:80`. To get that to work with your SSL version you need to:

1. Listen for HTTP (not HTTPS) on port 80
2. Issue a 301 HTTP Redirect to the SSL site

If you type `my.ip.address:443` into a browser, then it will request `http://my.ip.address:443`. This will try to make an HTTP request without setting up SSL first and get an error. There is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Your answer was actually quite helpful. I'm now able to make all the first three urls work. Are you sure there's nothing I can do about the last one (my.ip.address:443)?

Comment: @JesseJames — It might be possible to write something that sniffs incoming data on port 443 and responses with HTTP or SSL depending on what it gets, but it seems like a lot of work for a really weird edge case. People aren't in the habit of explicitly putting port numbers in URLs, let alone doing what without using the scheme.

Answer (score 1):

You can make redirects from http to https.
Via nginx

https://github.com/vodolaz095/hunt/blob/master/examples/serverConfigsExamples/nginx.conf#L22-L39

```
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org;
    rewrite      ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
  }
```

Via expressjs middleware

https://github.com/vodolaz095/hunt/blob/master/examples/index.js#L133-L139

something like this:

```
app.use(function (request, response, next) {
  if (request.protocol === 'http') {
    response.redirect('https://yourhostname.com' + request.originalUrl);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Great answer. I was already able to do that. But what I'm really trying to do right now is to make it work when i type my.ip.address:443 (this should work and redirect me to https:// my.ip.address.

Comment: Do you mean redirect from `http://my.ip.address:443` (yes, http) to `https://my.ip.address:443` (yes, https) ? Probably you have to bind application or nginx to 2 ports - the 80 (default to http) and 443 (default to https)

Comment: Binding two different ports isn't going to help you deal with two different protocols coming on on *the same port*